# New Google Analytics in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-analytics, analytics

I was notified on official Google Analytics page that there are some changes in how to integrate Google Analytics in an Android app. For now I was using this method

```
private static GoogleAnalytics analytics;

private static Tracker tracker;

public static GoogleAnalytics analytics() {
    return analytics;
}

public static Tracker tracker() {
    return tracker;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    tracker = analytics.newTracker("xxx");
    tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);

}
```

But when I want to add this method in a new application I don't get any data in Analytics, not even real-time. Are there some changes in SDK?

I don't use Android Studio, but Eclipse but Google now requires some configuration file for Analytics which we must downloaded from their [webpage](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)...

Any suggestion how to fix this issue?